# MySQL Selecting from one table while needing data from other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such tables:

[image]

How to, with just SQL select all the comments, for tracks with the genre of 'xxx'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could do that in two way first:

```
 SELECT commmentId, content, date
 FROM comments
 WHERE trackId IN (SELECT trackId 
                   FROM tracks
                   WHERE genreId = xxx);
```

Or:

```
SELECT c.commentId, c.content, c.date, t.genreId
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN tracks t
ON c.trackId = t.trackId
WHERE t.genreId = xxx;
```

And I didn't understand very well if you want to select comments by genreId or by genre name (if you want to do that by name than you should extend this a little bit) but this is the logic you should fallow...